# BoltDB: periodically flush to disk

Tags: database, go, key-value, in-memory-database, boltdb

I'm writing an application that requires me to store a very large map with key-value pairs. So relying solely on a Golang map in memory will not cut it. 
BoltDB looks like it might be the right thing for this scenario.

My application will continuously write and delete (+retrieve the deleted value) values on a single key-value store. **For performance reasons I want to avoid a new BoltDB db.Update every time I write a value as this would also write to disk.** However, I want to periodically flush the in-memory state back to the file the BoltDB relies on to avoid running out-of-memory.

How can this be achieved with BoltDB? Is it feasible to create a single BoltDB transaction (db.Update) for my application and call tx.Commit periodically to flush to disk?

Comment: Sure, if you're OK with the potential data loss. Anything that has not been flushed will be lost if the program exits due to a crash, system failure, etc.

Comment: Did you experience actual performance problems? Bolt is quite fast. And in case you have, are you positively sure that they are stemming from Bolt?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I was asking out of precaution because I have an insanely work-heavy task at hand that is likely to run for days. Therefore I want to get as much performance as possible and committing each write seemed to be a very bad idea to me. Now I've started experimenting with Bolt and it seems to run fine. The only issue I'm facing is that with a growing DB size that now exceeds my memory, the system is constantly swapping. However, this may very well be totally unrelated to Bolt and a memory leak of my application.

Comment: Bolt uses memory mapped files so that makes sense